# C++: separating first and last name from a file, separated by a comma

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I have this as a file:

```
Collins,Bill 80
Smith,Bart 75
Allen,Jim 82
Griffin,Jim 55
Stamey,Marty 90
Rose,Geri 78
Taylor,Terri 56
Johnson,Jill 77
Allison,Jeff 45
Looney,Joe 89
Wolfe,Bill 63
James,Jean 72
Weaver,Jim 77
Pore,Bob 91 
Rutherford,Greg 42
Javens,Renee 74
Harrison,Rose 58
Setzer,Cathy 93
Pike,Gordon 48
Holland,Beth 79
```

As you can see the last name and first name are separated with a comma.

Right now I have this in my code:

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open ("students.txt");

string studentNames;            // Student names - Last name followed by first
int studentMarks = 0;           // Student mark for text/exam

// Read in data from students.txt
inputFile >> studentNames;
inputFile >> studentMarks;

// IF file has too much data, output WARNING
if (numElts >= NUM_NAMES)
{
    cout << "Error: File contains too many lines of data, check the file." << endl << endl;
}
else
{
    names[numElts] = studentNames;
    marks[numElts] = studentMarks;
    numElts++;
}
```

I want to bypass these commas, I want to store it as firstname and then last name which then I will just merge into name like `name = firstname " " last name`.   How should I do that, please?

Comment: 1. Read in the entire `firstname,lastname` token as you're currently doing.  2. Find where the comma is with `string::find()`.  3. Create 2 new substrings with this information.

Comment: Wait how do I use this find so just underneath inputFile >> studentNames; I would put studentNames.find(","); but then what? How do I get rid of it or what do I do after I have found this comma?

Comment: If you can't figure out what to do from what I just said and *90 seconds* on Google, then I'm sorry but you're way out of your conceptual depth for this kind of exercise.  You need to learn about what a string is and the various basic operations that can be performed on it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to remove the `,` and get the first name last with space between,

```
    string output;
    int position = studentNames.find(',');
    for(int i=position+1;i<studentNames.size();i++)
        output+=studentNames[i];
    output+=' ';
    for(int i=0;i<position;i++)
        output+=studentNames[i];
    studentNames = output;
```

Comment: I don't think we are allowed to use additional functions. I am limited to some ones that were set up and told to work in those so I can't. All of this is already within a function.

Comment: So although the data was last name, first name, this will switch it around to first and last? How does it do so? It captures both names?

Comment: It searches for the coma. Then it stores all the characters after the coma position in `output`. Which is the first name. Then it stores all the characters from first position to the position immediately before the coma in 'output'. which is the last name.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string::size_type commaPos = studentName.find(",");
std::string studentLastName = studentName.substr(0, commaPos);
std::string studentFirstName = studentName.substr(commaPos + 1);
```

Comment: I'm really new to c++, I do not understand what :: are used as and I use namespace std; at the top. This is my very first c++ class. The first like confuses me so I want to understand.

Comment: Read to learn about namespace in http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/711-namespaces/

Comment: Thank you that link is very helpful since our prof didn't really explain these things at all.

Comment: @tinywolves: Piece of advice, *don't* use using directives `using namespace XXX;`. Qualification will help you understand where each function call comes from.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But our class requires to use these. This makes thing very confusing since teacher says one thing and online everyone uses something else. I don't get why or why do they bother teaching us these ways if they are no good?

Comment: @tinywolves, it is a matter of style whether you put `using namepace std;` or not. I imagine your teacher does it that way to make the examples shorter doing it that was is not "no good". My snippet will still work fine if you have `using namespace std;` but you can remove the 'std::' if you like.